# cycles visibility for multiple objects

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

**Is there any way to change the ray visibility of multiple objects (say from selected)?**

I have been trying to say make 150 objects invisible for diffuse - do i have to go by hand?

or is there way to write

```
bpy.context.object.cycles_visibility.* = True/False
```

but not to object?

Comment: @RayMairlot I think this more about python than the linked question, which explains UI ways to do this.

Comment: @stacker Possible. I thought the python tag was more because they thought there wouldn't be a ui solution, not that they didn't want one.

Comment: @RayMairlot you can't *copy_to_selected* cycles visibility, so how does the duplicate question answer it? Did you try it and those addons before marking it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Jerryno that's very odd, I'm sure I did it in previous versions, but you're right, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

Paste this into text editor and run it for your selection:

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     obj.cycles_visibility.diffuse = False
```